# Problem referring to members of an anonymous type in linq

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-6

I get this error referring to UserID in the line `Value = x.UserID` and similar ones in the following line referring to FirstName and LastName.  It says it understands that they are in the anonymous type, but still says there is no definition.

> 'IGrouping<, tblWorkorder>' does not contain a definition for 'UserID' and
>   no accessible extension method 'UserID' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'IGrouping<, tblWorkorder>' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

```
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetEnteredBy()
    {
        using (var context = new FacilityEntities())
        {
            List<SelectListItem> user = context.tblWorkOrder.AsNoTracking().Include("tblUser")
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.tblUser.LastName, x.tblUser.FirstName, x.tblUser.UserID })
                .Select(x =>
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = x.UserID,
                    Text = string.Concat(x.FirstName, " ", x.LastName)
                }).ToList();
            var usertip = new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = null,
                Text = "Select"
            };
            user.Insert(0, usertip);
            return new SelectList(user, "Value", "Text");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The error is: 'IGrouping<<anonymous type: string LastName, string FirstName, int UserID>, tblWorkorder>' does not contain a definition for 'UserID' and no accessible extension method 'UserID' accepting a first argument of type 'IGrouping<<anonymous type: string LastName, string FirstName, int UserID>, tblWorkorder>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `key` property on group items

This is how you can do

```
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetEnteredBy()
    {
        using (var context = new FacilityEntities())
        {
            List<SelectListItem> user = context.tblWorkOrder.AsNoTracking().Include("tblUser")
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.tblUser.LastName, x.tblUser.FirstName, x.tblUser.UserID })
                .Select(x =>
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = x.Key.UserID,
                    Text = string.Concat(x.Key.FirstName, " ", x.Key.LastName)
                }).ToList();
            var usertip = new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = null,
                Text = "Select"
            };
            user.Insert(0, usertip);
            return new SelectList(user, "Value", "Text");
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.